# Upgrade to EE3 breaks MSM

Tags: multi-site-manager

I'm a little confused here and haven't found anything the clearly explains this. I recently upgraded our EE2 site to EE3. Previously we had purchased the MSM with 16 sites. After upgrading to EE3 none of my subsites work.. the screen is just blank. Do i now have to purchase a full $199 for each site or is something else going on here? Any info is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do need to upgrade the MSM site licenses. The updates are $99 USD each.

https://expressionengine.com/blog/expressionengine-3-pricing-and-upgrades

Comment: Thanks. I don't have the option to upgrade my MSM licenses? I can either add an additional MSM site to EE2 or a full additional site to EE3. See screenshot. I have several MSM sites that aren't working now. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry.. i don't see where i can add a screenshot

Comment: Under 'Purchases' on the EE site, I see 2 options for EE2 sites under the upgrade tab: "Don't Link MSM License - $149" -- that's site update only. Below that I see a list of MSM licenses with the license numbers that haven't been upgraded yet and can choose the appropriate one.

Why EL does it this way, instead of attaching the specific, associated MSM sites with the specific, associated EE license, I don't know.  But if you are not seeing this, send EL support an email to get upgraded. support@ellislab.com

Comment: Maybe this was an option when i upgraded my EE2 site to EE3 but i didn't select it? Regardless, I don't have the option to do it now so I'm stuck. I emailed support@ellislab.com. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No prob! EL should be able sort it out for you.